# Convert charset from a entire project to utf-8

Tags: linux, bash, unix, character-encoding

Hi i have a project made in windows who uses windows 1252 charset and i need to convert all my .php file to utf-8 charset because my database is all utf-8 encoded.
Is there a way to do that using linux commands or a software?

Comment: It would only take a few lines of Python to convert a single file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your project's root directory, use [find(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) to list all `*.php` files and combine that with [recode(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/recode) to convert those files in place:

```
find . -type f -name '*.php' -exec recode windows1252..utf8 \{} \;
```

As an alternative to recode(1), you could also use [iconv(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/iconv) to do the conversion (for usage with above `find` command: `iconv -f windows-1252 -t utf-8 -o \{} \{}`).

You need to have either recode or iconv installed for the above to work. Both should be easily installable via a package manager on most modern systems.

Comment: well i got this find -type f -name '*.php' -exec recode windows1252..utf8 \{} \;
find: illegal option -- t
usage: find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]
       find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]

Comment: with the dot it goes ok but it says find: recode: No such file or directory

Comment: oh i found it, i needed to install recode with brew install, thanks man saved my day

Answer (score 1):

To convert a single file using Python (since I was asked...)

```
import codecs
with codecs.open(filename_in, 'r', 'windows-1252') as fin:
    with codecs.open(filename_out, 'w', 'utf-8') as fout:
        for line in fin:
            fout.write(line)
```

It is also possible to encode to utf-8 directly into a string without writing it to a file:

```
utf8_line = line.encode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar case but where all files were not encoded in ISO-8859. Some were encoded in ASCII or UTF-8. Using a bare `find ... -exec iconv ...` screwed up my git repo and I had to reclone it.

Here is what I used to avoid wrong conversions:

```
for f in $(find . -type f); do file $f | grep -q ISO-8859 && iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 -o $f $f; done
```