# "symfony new project-name" command generates files in ISO-9958-1 encoding

Tags: symfony, character-encoding, symfony4

Can somebody tell me why

```sh
symfony new project-name --full
```

generates files in ISO-8859-1 encoding? As I found out right now files are not in UTF-8 encoding. Why is it so and how can I change it to UTF-8? How to ensure that commands like `make:form` will generate UTF-8 files?

I am on Windows 10.

Comment: how this matter to you? why you care how it stores data in the files? if output is done on utf-8 from the web server, who cares how it stored in files? There is a way to convert files to utf-8 in phpstorm IDE.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680134/convert-charset-from-a-entire-project-to-utf-8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very likely your text editor getting confused or "assuming" an incorrect encoding..

`symfony new project-name --full` simply creates the project using `composer`. Specifically it calls:

```
composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton
```

Which in turn calls `git clone`, and that's it.

Files are not really "generated", but simply cloned from the appropriate Git repository. And Git will straight retrieve the files as they exist in the repository, without applying any kind of transformation.

So files will use whatever encoding they have in the original repositories. Which, as far as I can see and as much as it  matters... it already **is** UTF-8.

But more importantly, almost all —with very few exceptions— files only include characters in the ASCII range... and since UTF-8 is a superset of ASCII, files without characters outside the ASCII range are undistinguishable as UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1.

On top of that, the actual encoding for the files is largely irrelevant, apart from very specific places (e.g. hard-coded strings that will be used as output).

My guess is that in the absence of special characters or [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), your text editor is defaulting to show the files as if they were "encoded" in the default encoding for the editor, because if you add any characters beyond the ASCII range, those will be encoded using ISO-8859-1.

The solution is to change the settings of whatever code editor you use so it defaults to UTF-8.

Comment: It seems it is true. Now it is working. Does not know why I saw that ? in the output. Cant replicate it again.